# Clean Rails way to have a child collection linked by checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, has-many

This is the thing

I have a table/class called `Offer`

And referenced table/class called `OfferDay` (because an Offer is available on x days of the week)

It's just a really simple question.

Is there a Ruby on Rails convention for editing such a thing?

My `Offer` admin form should have 7 checkboxes, prefilled with `OfferDays` for this instance (or not)

Yes of course, i can loop days of the week in my .erb and check the child collection (days) of the instance, but what about auto binding to instances on postbacK? - it seems the sort of legwork we've all seen before and should have a convention.

Yes I've googled... found sort of it, but not quite... any specific to this one?

Comment: This is quite a vague question - very hard to answer. it is also primarily opinion-based, which means it's going to trigger close-votes. I'd consider showing us the code you have, and letting us help iterate towards a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd handle it with a [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) relationship:

```
#app/models/offer.rb
Class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :days, -> { select(:day_id) }, class_name: "OfferDay", foreign_key: "offer_id"
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :days
end

Class OfferDay < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :offer
end

offer_days
id | offer_id | day_id #-> put indexes on day_id & offer_id
```

You'll be able to call `@offer.days` to reveal the days on which your offer is running. It will of course return a number, which you'll then translate into a day using the [`Date` class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html) or similar

---

**Editing**

This will allow you to assign any number of days to each offer (and each of the days being unique). I'd update like this:

```
#app/controllers/offers_controller.rb
def new
   @offer = Offer.new
   @offer.days.build
end

def create
   @offer = Offer.new(offer_params)
   @offer.save
end

private

def offer_params
    params.require(:offer).permit(:offer, :attributes, days_attributes: [:day_id])
end

#app/views/offers/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @offer do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :offer %>
   <%= f.text_field :attributes %>
   <%= f.fields_for :days do |builder| %>
       <% 7.times do |day| %>
          <%= builder.check_box :day_id, day %> #-> need label for each day
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. The form is not right though. If we have say 5 days or already filled and we come to edit, we see 35 (7x5) checkboxes. Equally for a new record we do not see any checkboxes at all..

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - would you like me to edit it for you? I see you've edited the answer (don't know if you've fixed it yourself!)

Comment: just working on what feels a bit hackish but may work - returning after the first iteration of `f.fields_for :days` - but that would not solve the new record issue

Comment: That smelled too bad so in the end, ive used loops and checkbox_tags and some (traditional) custom handling of child records in the controller...but thanks I learnt from the post